# Compare tow Vector3 localScale then add it to another GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to calculate two  localScale value's Proportion

the normal one and the enlarge one.

Then make another GameObject multiply this Proportion

like this

```
var localscaleA = GameObjectA.transform.localscale.


var Proportion = GameObjectA.transform.localScale/ GameObjectAenlarge.transform.localScale; 

GameObjectB.transform.localScale = GameObjectB.transform.localScale * Proportion ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do this component wise e.g.

```
var localscaleA = GameObjectA.transform.localscale;
var localscaleAEnlarge = GameObjectAenlarge.transform.localScale;
var Proportion = new Vector3(localscaleAEnlarge.x / localScaleA.x, localscaleAEnlarge.y / localScaleA.y, localscaleAEnlarge.z / localScaleA.z);
GameObjectB.transform.localScale = Vector3.Scale(GameObjectB.transform.localScale, Proportion);
```